# the meaning of 'faintly' in 'a faintly comical figure'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I've come across this sentence in the entry for **comical** in [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/comical?q=comical)

> *He is a **faintly comical** figure who fears being made fun of.*

Is ***faintly*** in the sentence positive or negative? In other words, does it mean he is a little comical or barely comical(not comical at all)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/faintly defines *faintly* as

> slightly or not strongly:

> She seemed faintly embarrassed to see us there.

> A light flickered faintly in the distance.

The example means

> He is a *slightly* comical figure who fears being made fun of.

It also means he is *a little comical*.

Comment: Thank you.:)
I've also looked up those definitions but I wasn't sure how to interpret it.